# What are Canvas apps and how to use them for below scenario?

Tags: canvas

I need to add a external CTI application which they have as a separated web application and i need to add the application to salesforce

can i use canvas apps to achieve this ? and The application has username and password authentication how does that be handled in canavas app

Do we need to only provide the base login url as canvas url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTI integration requires a [CTI adapter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_intro.htm). Your vendor may have one that you can use. For some services, you can develop your own if they have a documented API. Canvas apps, on the other hand, are used to integrate a third-party app into Salesforce. Authentication is handled by Salesforce automatically. It is likely not suitable for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox